# Ionic POST not data

Tags: php, angularjs, angular, post, ionic-framework

**I need help to request a post from an Ionic page**
I am trying to make a login application, in the future I will put a Token system so I need to send a POST to the server and return the data, but when I try to send the POST, it does not arrive with the DATA sent, PHP with $ _POST [`email`] for example...

my page provider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiURL = "http://192.168.64.2/irewards/api/";

/*
  Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  postData(credentials, type){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let header = new Headers();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials));
      this.http.post(apiURL + type, JSON.stringify(credentials),  { headers: header }).subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) => reject(err));
    });
  }

}
```

my page Login

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  responseData: any;
  userData = { "email":"", "pass":"" };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: AuthServiceProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  openRegister(){
    this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  signin(){
    this.authService.postData(this.userData, "users.class.php").then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      console.log(this.responseData);
      //localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
      //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }, (err) => console.log(err));
  }

}
```

and my page PHP

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include 'connect.pdo.class.php';

$objConn = new Connect();
$conn = $objConn->getInstance();

function loginUser($email, $pass){
  $users = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `pass` = ?");
  $users->execute(array($email, $pass));
  echo json_encode($users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];

  loginUser($email, $pass);
}
?>
```

if change $_POST for $_GET it returns everything I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the http post is sending data in Input Stream. You cannot access it with $_POST.
To access the data you need to use `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` and then in your code you can access `$data['email']`.
It could also be possible that your data is jsonencoded. In such cases use `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

If you want to access data via $_POST then you need to send you POST data with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: im add header("Acess-Control-Allow=Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); in PHP page

Comment: You don't add that in PHP. You need to add it in your Ionic http request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';` and headers ex: `var options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      })`
when post example: `this.http.post(url, post, options).then((data) => ...`